# How to pipe JSON to function in node.js?

Tags: json, node.js

I asked this question:

[How to pipe to function in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169980/node-js-how-to-pipe-to-function)

But I find that it's not as easy when using JSON. Because the JSON is streamed in chunks, it breaks when you try to `JSON.parse` a chunk that does not represent a complete JSON object.

The following code works fine for small JSON files but breaks for large JSON files. How do I do this when streaming large JSON files?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const {Transform} = require('stream')

const jsonTransform = new Transform({
    readableObjectMode: true,
    writableObjectMode: true,
    transform: (chunk, encoding, done) => {
        let json = JSON.parse(chunk)
        // manipulate json here
        done(null, JSON.stringify(json, null, 2))
    }
})

fs.createReadStream('input.json')
    .pipe(jsonTransform)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.json'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a tonne of modules on npm handling this, e.g. `JSONstream` by Dominic Tarr https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream

Another approach is to ensure the json in your `input.json` is newline delimited (ndjson) and then you can use https://github.com/maxogden/ndjson to parse each line into an object and you can pipe that further to something modifying the objects and stringifying the contents.

Comment: thanks will give others a chance to answer if not will accept this, this is great info but was hoping to learn how to do this without any deps, PS i wont forget to accept an answer, I review my questions periodically to make sure I have accepted